# Log symplectic vortex equations in Hamiltonian log GW theory

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, gromov-witten-theory

Hamiltonian Gromov-Witten theory(see [Mundet-Tian](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404407) paper) corresponds to a new type of Symplectic vortex equations: Such type of models gives a connection to [Hitchin-Kobayashi correspondenc](http://docenti.math.unipd.it/dagnolo/Padova2014/slides/sakai.pdf)e and Floer theory(for example Donaldson's book: Floer homology groups in Yang–Mills theory).

Question:

Take the vortex equations with values in a symplectic manifold
$(M, \omega)$. We assume that $(M, \omega)$ is equipped with a Hamiltonian action by a
compact Lie group $G$ that is generated by an equivariant moment map
$\mu : M \to \mathfrak g$.
The symplectic vortex equations have the form
$$\overline ∂_{J,A}(u) = 0, \; \; ∗F_A + \mu(u) = \tau\in \mathcal Z(\mathfrak g)$$
Here $ P\to  Σ$ is a principal $G$-bundle over a compact Riemann surface, $u :
P → M $ is an equivariant smooth function, and $A$ is a connection on $P$.

Now how can we extend the study of symplectic vortex equations to logarithmic setting. In fact if we assume $M$ is a log-symplectic manifold, then  [Gualtieri- Li-Pelayo and Ratiu](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00208-016-1427-9) developed log symplectic reduction and log moment map. So the study of Log symplectic vortex equations in Hamiltonian [Log GW theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.00224.pdf) or its Hitchin-Kobayashi type correspondencis natural to be considered. Is there any progress about it. Any reference or comment is welcomed

Comment: Is there any approach to stydy of symplectic vortex equations on symplectic singularities(instead symplectic manifold) in the sense of Beauville? http://math1.unice.fr/~beauvill/pubs/symp.pdf . I am mainly interested to know any approach on this ground. In fact we have some sort of moment map on symplectic variety https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.05154.pdf. So the study of the singular version of Mundet-Tian paper is natural proposal to ask.